# Chemfig: reaction mechanism problem: arrow position

Tags: chemfig

[image]

Hello everybody.
 As you all can see the curved arrow doesn't point to the positive carbon as it should, but it kink of turn around the bond.
How can I solve this?
Thanks in advance for any answer!

```
\schemestart
\chemfig{@{a2}C^{\oplus}(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:180]CH_3)(-[:270]CH_3)}\chemfig{\+ @{a1}Cl^{\ominus}}\arrow{<=>}\chemfig{C(-[:0]Cl)(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:180]CH_3)(-[:270]CH_3)}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw(a1)..  controls +(100:5mm) and +(145:5mm)..  (a2);}
```

Comment: Try @{a2}{C^{\oplus}} instead.

Comment: Nothing changed

Comment: Well, you can try to draw to (a2.east) in addition, and if that doesn't help, please provide a complete minimal working example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write instead

```
\schemestart
\chemfig{@{a2}C^{\oplus}(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:180]CH_3)(-[:270]CH_3)}\chemfig{\+ @{a1}Cl^{\ominus}}
\arrow{<=>}\chemfig{C(-[:0]Cl)(-[:90]CH_3)(-[:180]CH_3)(-[:270]CH_3)}
\schemestop
\chemmove{\draw(a1)..  controls +(100:5mm) and +(45:5mm)..  (a2);}
```

[image]